# Displaying shell sorting process

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    numberSort();
}

public static void numberSort(){
    int quantity = 0;
    int allocate = 0;
    quantity = Integer.parseInt( 
               JOptionPane
                 .showInputDialog("How many values do you wish to sort? : "));

    int[] values = new int[quantity];

    for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++){
        allocate = Integer.parseInt(
                          JOptionPane
                             .showInputDialog("Values you want to sort : "));
        values[x] = allocate;
    }

    int lenD = values.length;
    int inc = lenD/2;

    while(inc>0){
        for(int i=inc;i<lenD;i++){
            int tmp = values[i];
            int j = i;
            while(j>=inc && values[j-inc]>tmp){
                values[j] = values[j-inc];
                j = j-inc;
            }
        values[j] = tmp;
        }
        inc = (inc /2);
    }

    System.out.print(values);
}
```

I have another question, this code is connected on my first question. It's all about Shell sort. I don't know if my loop is right but i'm having a problem on how to print the step by step process and the final output of the sort. Thanks

My question is how to print the output of the shell sort and do a visualization of the said sort.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to print out the values of your sorted array. Is that correct?

If so, there are a few ways to do this.

Currently, your `System.out.println(values);` code is defaulting to the `toString` method of `Object` which is why you see something similar to this: `[I@6db22920` as the output.

A quick and easy way to print out an array is to use the `Arrays.toString(values);` code. This call will print your sorted integers like so:

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 15, 19, 57]
```

You could also manually iterate through the array using a for loop and print the values one by one. This would be done like so:

```
for(int currentInt : values) {
    System.out.println(currentInt);
}
```

The above for loop code would print the values one by one on separate lines like so:

```
2
3
4
6
8
9
11
15
19
57
```

Does this resolve your question?